# Name scope for finding emails from table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, named-scope

In the user table I have a name field, where some records are names, and some are emails.  I know, bad  approach. That aside. I'd like to write a named scope that returns only email records.

I've tried adapting a query that does this query, and failed.

**MYSQL:**

```
SELECT NAME
FROM USER
WHERE NAME LIKE '%@%.%'
```

**User model:**

```
scope :user_email, :conditions => ["name like '%@%.%'"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :user_email, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", '%@%.%']
```

You should provide string conditions in this format to avoid possible sql injection problems.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 named_scope :user_email, :conditions => ["name REGEXP ?", /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i]
```